# How to add trailing zero's in a string with c#?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, formatting, trailing

I have amounts with decimals (300.11 and 9801.98), I export them Excel and everything is fine.

But sometimes I have amounts with trailing zeros, and I want to keep those zeros when exporting? For example 300.00 becomes 300 when exporting to Excel. How can I fix this?

This is the code right before the export happens.

AmountCCC is of type double.

```
row.Amount = row.AmountCCC.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

See in the screenshot how the records are exported.

[image]

Comment: Do you always need 2 digit precision for this column ?

Comment: How do you write in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `N2`

```
row.AmountCCC.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString)